# Show that $f^2\in L([0,1]).$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am doing my homework and I have almost no idea for this problem.

> Let $f\in L([0,1])$ and let $g$ be a finite-valued and monotone increasing function defined on $[0,1]$. Assume for any sub-interval $[a,b]\subset[0,1],$ there holds
> $$\left|\displaystyle\int\limits_a^b f(x)\text{dx}\right|^2 \le [g(b)-g(a)](b-a).$$
> Show that $f^2\in L([0,1]).$

So the only thing I know is that since $g$ is a monotone increasing function on $[0,1]$ then $g$ is differentiable almost everywhere and $g$ is also Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$.

Can you please give me any hints on this? I am appreciated alot.

Comment: HInt: Use the Lebesgue differentiation theorem and the facts you mention about $g$.

Comment: @Jose27 Thanks to your hint, I am able to get that 
$$\lim\limits_{a\to b} \int_0^1\left|\dfrac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(t)dt -f(x) \right|dx=0$$ and 
$$ \int_0^1\left|\dfrac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(t)dt\right|^2dx\leq \int_0^1 g'(x)dx $$ 
However,  I still don't know how to show that $\int_0^1 f^2(x)dx <\infty$ since I can't see the connection between them...

Comment: You don't need the outside integral in the first equation of your comment (for what I had in mind when I mentioned differentiation).

Comment: @Jose27 I see, the name was incorrect when I first wrote it in my note. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|^{2}dx&=\int_{0}^{1}\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\left|\frac{1}{|B_{h}(x)|}\int_{B_{h}(x)}f(y)dy\right|^{2}dx\\
&\leq\int_{0}^{1}\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\left|\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}\right|dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}|g'(x)|dx\\
&<\infty.
\end{align*}

Comment: How to prove $|g'(x)| < \infty$ uniformly since monotonic functions can have discontinuities. $g(x)$ may not even be differentiable

Comment: Thank you. But isn't it should be $\int_0^1|f(x)|^2dx$ at the begining right?

Comment: @Balajisb There is a theorem in Royden's book states that an increasing function on the closed, bounded interval $[a,b]$ is differentiable almost everywhere on $(a,b)$ and $f'$ is integrable.

Comment: The typo has been corrected, thank you.